# is it possible RDPSession outside the network?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, desktop-sharing

I am able to create an application for screen sharing using RDPsession within the network, but is it possible outside the network?

or any other way to connect between host and viewer outside the network other than rdpsession?

Any hint or help will be appreciated greatly..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just show or controll an appication a program like [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?utm_expid=60202728-11&utm_referrer=http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=teamviewer&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.teamviewer.com%252F&ei=1JkbUKOyOce4hAf4oIHgBg&usg=AFQjCNGHCZ-GmRwuRFVdksOAVFXeCWTYwg) could do the trick or any other VNC application. If you are set on running a RDP session to your computer from outside the network, you well need to setup [NAT forwardin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)g on your router. the TCP port will be 3389 and you will need to assign that forwarding to your machines from inside the network IP. All routers are different so you will need to find out how to do this for your routers model. Also you must obtain a Public static IP address from your ISP, if you don't have one already. If you are not allowed to change router settings or not allowed to get a Static IP you could use a VPN client like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/uk/products/hamachi/download.aspx).

Comment: I am not using any 3rd party tools but developing a screen sharing application.